# How to wait 30 second after 20 requests selenium scraping

Tags: selenium, export-to-csv, scrape, pause

Hello i have a csv file 300 datas.

After 10 requests , the website stop to give me results.

How to pause 3 minutes my script after 10 requests

thanks you

my code :

```
societelist =[]


import csv



with open('1.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
  for row in reader:
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    browser.get("myurl".format(row[0]))
    time.sleep(20) 

    try:
        societe = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        societe = 'Element not found'

    societelist.append(societe)
    print (row[0])
    browser.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(societelist)), columns=['societe'])

data = df.to_csv('X7878.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import csv
societelist =[]

with open('1.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):       # i gives the index of the row.
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        browser.get("myurl".format(row[0]))
        time.sleep(20) 

        try:
            societe = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            societe = 'Element not found'

        societelist.append(societe)
        print(row[0])
        browser.quit()
        if not ((i+1) % 10):    
            time.sleep(180)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(societelist)), columns=['societe'])
df.to_csv('X7878.csv', index=False)
```

Alternate solution to write each line of text to Excel after scraping instead of writing all text at once.

```
import csv
import win32com.client as win32

# Launch excel
excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = 1
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Sheets(1)

# Read csv and scrape webpage
with open('1.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):       # i gives the index of the row.
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        browser.get("myurl".format(row[0]))
        time.sleep(20) 

        try:
            societe = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            societe = 'Element not found'

        # it may make sense to write the input text and the scraped value side by side.
        ws.Cells(i+1, 1).Value = row[0]
        ws.Cells(i+1, 2).Value = societe

        print(row[0], societe)
        browser.quit()
        if not ((i+1) % 10):    
            time.sleep(180)

# If you want to save the file programmatically and close excel.
path = r'C:\Users\jarodfrance\Documents\X7878.xlsx'
wb.SaveAs(path)
wb.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Comment: The quick and 'dirty' approach would be to move the last 2 lines of code before `browser.quit()`. It will create a dataframe for each row and overwrite the previous CSV file. However, I do not recommend it. The proper way is to use an excel library, but it depends on why you want to view the output dynamically in the first place.